# Does anyone know how to change the layout xml so that the toolbar doesn't cover the items?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-emulator, android-toolbar

Thanks!!

**Here is the main xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout     
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#EFC6D4"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <include
        android:id="@+id/include"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/electric_time_capital"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appBarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="669dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/include"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="center" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And here is the layout xml:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"-->
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:id="@+id/parent_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="center_horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/image_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="31dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="31dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="202dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/image"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/image"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Walking"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="17sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
<!--</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>-->
```

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QReo.png)
[layout xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFOVM.png)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hardcoding the RecyclerView height, just use ConstraintLayout as your root layout and constraint the top of the RecyclerView to the bottom of the AppBarLayout.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not attached any image about how you want your layout to be, I am assuming that your requirements are:

1. **AppBarLayout** with **Toolbar** containing title "Electric Time Capital"
2. The layout **content_main** below the **toolbar**
3. The **RecyclerView** below the layout **content_main**
4. **FloatingActionButton** at the bottom right

   ```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="#EFC6D4"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/electric_time_capital"
                    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <include
            android:id="@+id/include"
            layout="@layout/content_main"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/appBarLayout" />

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="669dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/include"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/include" /> 
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
   ```

> Note: Use [ConstraintLayout](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout) as it is easier to make responsive
> layouts. It might look tricky when you use it for the first time, but it is the
> best approach!

Happy Coding!